# OpenGL bug only present when run without debugging, how is it possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm having a strange bug when writing a tiny OpenGL application. When I run the application with F5 (w/Debugging) in Visual Studio, it runs well. If I run it with Ctrl + F5 (w/o Debugging), it runs at 0 FPS. In both cases I'm using the "Release" build in Visual Studio.

How is it possible? **Is there anything different between the two ways of running a program, what should modify the run of a program?**  This is a crazy bug, somehow connected to AntTweakBar and drawing a large number objects + nVidia OpenGL drivers.

Here is the source code of the program (it's extremely tiny):

```
#include "cinder/app/AppBasic.h"
#include "cinder/gl/gl.h"
#include "cinder/params/Params.h"
#include "cinder/Rand.h"
#include "cinder/Camera.h"

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;

class params_slowApp : public AppBasic
{
    public:
        void setup();
        void update();
        void draw();
        void prepareSettings( Settings *settings );

        CameraPersp mCam;
        params::InterfaceGl mParams;
};

void params_slowApp::prepareSettings( Settings *settings )
{
    settings->setWindowSize( 1280, 720 );
    settings->setFrameRate( 300 );
}

void params_slowApp::setup()
{
    gl::enableVerticalSync( false );
    gl::enableAlphaBlending();

    mCam.setPerspective( 45.0f, getWindowAspectRatio(), 5.0f, 300000.0f );
    mCam.lookAt( Vec3f::zero(), -Vec3f::zAxis(), Vec3f::yAxis() );

    mParams = params::InterfaceGl( "controls", Vec2i( 200, 300 ) );
    mParams.addText( "text" );
}

void params_slowApp::update()
{
}

void params_slowApp::draw()
{
    gl::clear( Color( 0, 0, 0 ), true );

    gl::pushMatrices();
    gl::setMatrices( mCam );

    gl::enableDepthRead();
    gl::enableDepthWrite();

    for( int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
    {
        glColor4f( randFloat(), 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 );

        {
            gl::pushModelView();
            gl::translate( randFloat(-100,100), randFloat(-100,100), randFloat(-10,-100) );
            gl::drawCube( Vec3f::zero(), Vec3f::one() );
            gl::popModelView();
        }
    }

    gl::disableDepthWrite();
    gl::disableDepthRead();

    gl::popMatrices();

    params::InterfaceGl::draw();
}

CINDER_APP_BASIC( params_slowApp, RendererGl )
```

I'm using the [Cinder](http://libcinder.org/) framework, and if I do any of the following, the program runs at full speed (100 FPS), instead of 0 FPS:

- remove a .addText from AntTweakBar `mParams.addText( "text" );`
- remove AntTweakBar draw routine `params::InterfaceGl::draw();`
- remove the changing of colors `glColor4f( randFloat(), 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 );`
- remove the inner push-pull matrix and translation
- run on an Intel GPU instead of nVidia GPU

I'm trying to solve this problem, but this bug just seems weird to me. Can you recommend me a way to diagnose it? I have no control over AntTweakBar, and it's quite complicated so I don't know what inside makes it trigger this bug. It only happens when I have something drawn onto the AntTweakBar panel. [I've  already reported it](http://forum.libcinder.org/topic/parameters-interface-kills-performance-0-fps#23286000001338523) on Cinder's forum, but I believe it's not connected to Cinder. Are there any tools for diagnosing why does an OpenGL driver decides to go 0 FPS?

Comment: Release builds typically introduce compiler optimizations while debug usually doesn't. Try changing compiler optimization settings and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Bugs that only happen on release builds are typically caused by initialization and/or pointer-related issues.  For example, most compilers will initialize memory areas to some special constant if doing a debug build. Whereas in the release build, the memory will not be initialized and so during run-time, uninitialized variables will have random values.  So, double check that all your variables are initialized.  It would help if you could post your code.

Comment: Both builds are the same: Release. All the difference is running with F5 or Ctrl+F5.

Comment: @zsero: You get a different memory manager (Debug Heap) when your program starts up with a debugger attached.  Try using your debugger's "Attach to Process" function to connect to the program later, when it's already loaded without the Debug Heap.

Comment: Looks like a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug.

Comment: Run it through a GL debugger (http://www.gremedy.com/) and see if there are any unhandled GL errors

Comment: @ananthonline: I've just tried it with GL Debugger and of course the bug disappears.
@Ben Voigt: OK, I'm getting something: 5x these for each frame rendered: `First-chance exception at 0x004702e9 in params_slow.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x01f75948.` It _is_ present in the Debug build, but only if I use the "Attach to Process" thing, so I don't know how to actually use the debugger. Is it possible to know what components is making the access-violation? I mean nVidia driver, AntTweakBar, something with Cinder, etc?

Comment: Since it works ok with an Intel GPU, I would suspect the AntTweak code or your nVidia drivers - because you mention it works ok when you modify either.

Comment: The access violations seems to happen exactly when my bug is present. I found out that it's even present in the official compiled AntTweak examples! But only with nVidia graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you call `ShowWindow` before any OpenGL operations.